# Discuss the number of solution for a system of parametric equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, parametric

I need to discuss the number of solutions of the following parametric system.

$$\begin{cases}
  x^2+(m-4)x-5m-1=0\\
  2\le x\le4
\end{cases}$$

There is a hint saying to put $y=x^2$

So far I've proceded in the following way:
$x^2$ is not parametric so, unless I'm mistaken, the curve should represent a family of parables. Then the real solutions of the intersection with the $y=0$
axis are for $m^2+12m+20≥0$
, which gives $m1≤−10 \vee m2≥−2$

Unfortunately I'm struggling finding the intervals of $m$
where we get one or two solutions complying with the constraint $2\le x\le4$

The solution on the book is: 1 solution for $−5/3<m≤−1$
and 2 solutions for $−2≤m≤−5/3$

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has infinite solutions for $2 \leq x \leq 4$. Did you mean a parametric form for the solutions? Also, I'm not sure how putting $y=x^2$ is helpful.

Comment: It might be possible to express the solutions in terms of $m,$ by applying the quadratic equation. One would in that case have to say which $m$ values would lead to real solutions for $x$. [However if $x$ is allowed to be complex, nothing much can be said.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: If $x$ is real, then the two conditions place restrictions on the value of $m$ which can be found by resolving four cases. Perhaps that is what the exercise is asking for.

Comment: Ok let's see how I've proceded: $x^2$ is not parametric so, unless I'm mistaken, the curve should represent a family of parables. Then the real solutions of the intersection with $y=0$ axis are for $m^2+12m+20 \ge 0$, which gives $m1 \le -10$ or$m2 \ge-2$. Now I shoud find the intervals of $m$ where we get one or two solutions falling in the given interval

Comment: @MadBlack That is correct.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales thanks, but I'm struggling to conclude the exercise. Any advice? The book says: one solution for $-5/3 < m \le -1$ and two solutions for $-2 \le m \le -5/3$

Comment: @MadBlack The reason for the one downvote and the vote to close the question is that you have not shown any of your own work. If you edit your question and show the work you have completed so far, and by your previous comment it seems like you have done significant work, then I am sure someone will respond by showing you how to complete the exercise. If no one does so after a sufficient time, I will do so. Provided, that is, if you show your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what values of $m$ does

\begin{equation}
 f(x)=x^2+(m-4)x-(5m+1)\tag{1}
\end{equation}
have solution(s) on the interval $[2,4]$?

The equation $x^2+(m-4)x-(5m+1)=0$ has, for appropriate values of $m$, real solution(s)

$$ x=\frac{4-m\pm\sqrt{(m+2)(m+10)}}{2} $$

So in order for $x$ to be a real number it must be the case that either $m\le -10$ or $m\ge-2$.

Since the graph of $y=f(x)$ is a parabola there are at most two solutions for any given value of $m$ so we must find values of $m$ for which there are (A) one solution in $[2,4]$ or (B) two solutions in $[2,4]$.

Let us examine the double inequality.

\begin{equation}
 2\le\frac{4-m\pm\sqrt{(m+2)(m+10)}}{2}\le4\tag{2}
\end{equation}

This can be broken into the two double inequalities
\begin{equation}
 m\le\sqrt{(m+2)(m+10)}\le m+4\tag{3}
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
 -m-4\le\sqrt{(m+2)(m+10)}\le -m\tag{4}
\end{equation}

Fron the left inequality of (3) it can be concluded that $m\ge-2$ and from the right inequality that $-2\le m\le-1$ so $-2\le m\le-1$.

From the left inequality of (4) it can also be concluded that  $m\ge-2$ and from the right inequality that $-2\le m\le -\frac{5}{3}$.

So (2) is telling us that either $-2\le m\le-1$ or $-2\le m\le -\frac{5}{3}$. Therefore we should expect solutions for solutions of $f(x)=0$ to occur for values of $m$ lying in the interval $[-2,-1]$ and that perhaps there is something interesting happening at $m=-\frac{5}{3}$.

So we should first find what solutions of equation (1) lie in $[2,4]$ for the three critical values $m=-2,-\frac{5}{3},-1$.

When $m=-2$ equation (1) has one double solution, $x=3$ lying in the interval $[2,4]$ which by convention counts as two solutions.

When $m=-1$, equation (1) has two solutions but only one, $x=4$, which lies in the interval $[2,4]$.

When $m=-\frac{5}{3}$, equation (1) has two solutions, $x=2$ and $x=\frac{11}{3}$, both of which lie in the interval $[2,4]$.

To find out what is happening for values of $m$ in the interiors of intervals $\left[-2,-\frac{5}{3}\right]$ and $\left(-\frac{5}{3},-1\right]$.

For $m=-\frac{11}{6}$ halfway between $-2$ and $-\frac{5}{3}$ we find two solutions of (1) lying in the interval $[2,4]$ so we conclude that for $-2\le m\le -\frac{5}{3}$ there will be two solutions.

For $m=-\frac{4}{3}$ halfway between $-\frac{5}{3}$ and $-1$ we find two solutions of (1), but only one of the two solutions lies in the interval $[2,4]$, so we conclude that for $m\in\left(-\frac{5}{3},-1\right]$ only one solution of (1) lies in the interval $[2,4]$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oxkjalmcnj

- express $m=f(x)$, this gives a rational function, find its range over the interval $x\in[2,4]$ (i.e. boundary values $A$ and $B$ and minimum in $C$).
- since $f$ is $\searrow$ then $\nearrow$ and continuous on $[2,4]$ you can study initial problem on intervals $m\in[-2,-\frac 53]$ and $m\in[-\frac 53,-1]$
- express the two solutions $x_{min}$ and $x_{max}$ with quadratic formula and find their range for the two intervals considered (hint: $x_{min}\searrow$ and $x_{max}\nearrow$)
- conclude